# I am intent to abort the Scenario, however, the Scenario and Feature are reported as failed

Tags: karate

When some conditional Logic is satisfied, I am intent to stop running of the current scenario, which means the scenario is passed. However, the cucumber-reporting reported that the scenario and it's feature are failed.

I use karate.abort() function in the conditional Logic. You see the mainFlow/unhsFlow_v2.feature, there is no failed steps, but the scenario and feature are tagged as failed.

[image: you see the "mainFlow/unhsFlow_v2.feature" scenario and feature are failed]

It should be not be failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is fixed in the upcoming version 0.9.5 - there should be an RC out next week.

Here are the details: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/755

EDIT: `* configure abortedStepsShouldPass = true` should get you the behavior you want.